# Qt 5.6 - How to link QTreeWidget to the mainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

*Yop!*

*So I just started getting in-touch with QT ( being used to VS ) & I want to make a pretty simple form, nothing really "complex";*

*my goal is to setup my widget ( QTreeWidget ) to automatically take the size of MainWindow and update if the user ( me ) resize the form.*

*I know I could do that with some line of code but I'm pretty sure that it actually possible to set with layout using QTDesigner, my question is how can I do that?*

*help would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: You are correct. You can do that with [layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/layout.html) in Qt. (Deleted my earlier comment, as I posted it before reading your question in full.)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on parent form. Select "Layout" in context menu. If parent form has child widget you can select one of variants from menu drop-down (Grid, Vertical, Horizontal etc.). If parent form not has child elements those menu items will be disabled (((.

Comment: Put treeWidget on MainWindow. **Then right click on MainWindow**. Do what i say in answer (add layout to MainWindow). After that treeWidget take size of MainWindow. If you read my answer with attention you see parent form must have child widgets to activate additional "Layout" menu items.